# Add CSRF to assets for Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, playframework, playframework-2.0

I created an assetHandler to server static angular files but when I first request the handler it does not include any CSRF token as a cookie thus if I submit a form it does not include the CSRF token and I get the Unauthenticated User error.

Is it possible to explicitly set the CSRF token?

Here is the handler I created.

```
def assetHandler(file: String): Action[AnyContent] = {
    var name = file

    if (!file.contains(".")) {
      name = Seq("index.html").mkString
    }

    controllers.Assets.at("/public/lib/platform", name)
}
```

PS. If I first request another regular controller (e.g. /api/ping) Play sends the CSRF for that request and thus angular is able to use it in every request. Is it a good practise to call an extra controller?